# Improve CSV products import -> Array Category Query by name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, query-performance

recently we made a big change like build a new category tree for our website, and move over 2M products in the right category.

we have no performance issues, everything runs smoothly.

The only problem I have is that now the category tree is much more complex and deep, and it suffers when adding new articles via CSV import (timeout script, very slow, crash of script)
Basically a new product when it is added by CSV the category field is always textual (separated by "#")  example:   Engine#Crankshaft#Audi#Audi A5

So where is the problem is in my function for get the categoryID in case alredy exist in the database or not exist.  How i can improve? i think the main problem is in the very big array created

`protected function _getCategoriesID($field_value)
        {
            global $Database;
            $products_categories = array();
            $separator           = $this->_getSeparator($field_value);
            $category_array      = array();
            if ($separator != '') {
                $category_array = explode($separator, $field_value);
                $category_array = array_reverse($category_array);
            } else {
                $category_array[0] = $field_value;
            }
            unset($separator);
            $Qcategory = $Database->query('select c0.categories_id from :table_categories as c0 inner join :table_categories_description as cd on c0.categories_id=cd.categories_id where cd.categories_name = :categories_name and cd.language_id=:language_id');
            $Qcategory->bindTable(':table_categories', TABLE_CATEGORIES);
            $Qcategory->bindTable(':table_categories_description', TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION);
            $Qcategory->bindValue(':categories_name', $category_array[0]);
            $Qcategory->bindInt(':language_id', $this->language);
            $count = 1;
            if (count($category_array) > 1) {
                while ($count < count($category_array)) {
                    $Qcategory->appendQuery(' and c' . ($count - 1) . '.parent_id in (select c' . $count . '.categories_id from :table_categories' . $count . ' as c' . $count . ' inner join :table_categories_description' . $count . ' as cd' . $count . ' on c' . $count . '.categories_id=cd' . $count . '.categories_id where cd' . $count . '.categories_name = :categories_name' . $count . ' and cd' . $count . '.language_id=:language_id' . $count . ' ');
                    $Qcategory->bindTable(':table_categories' . $count, TABLE_CATEGORIES);
                    $Qcategory->bindTable(':table_categories_description' . $count, TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION);
                    $Qcategory->bindValue(':categories_name' . $count, $category_array[$count]);
                    $Qcategory->bindInt(':language_id' . $count, $this->language);
                    $count++;
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
                    $Qcategory->appendQuery(')');
                }
            }
            $Qcategory->execute();
            while ($Qcategory->next()) {
                $products_categories[] = $Qcategory->value('categories_id');
            }
            unset($Qcategories);
            return $products_categories;
        }`

Comment: *the category field is always textual (separated by "#") example: Engine#Crankshaft#Audi#Audi A5* Import into temptable, parse (one category per row), then save.

Comment: Please show us a sample of the generated SQL.